# Android: Access Content Provider from another application

Tags: android

I tried searching stackoverflow.com and tried every answer but none of them  work.

I have a content provider and it was working when the user of the content provider is in the same application. However, I have Permission Denial error when accessing from another application.

LogCat

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.BooksProvider from ProcessRecord{4174b338 18673:com.abc.contentprovidersuserbooks/u0a10112} (pid=18673, uid=10112) requires com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.READ_DATABASE or com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.WRITE_DATABASE
```

Content Provider AndroidManifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.abc.contentprovidersbooks"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name="com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.ContentProvidersBook"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:name="BooksProvider"
        android:authorities="com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.Books"
        android:readPermission="com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.READ_DATABASE"
        android:writePermission="com.abc.contentprovidersbooks.WRITE_DATABASE"
        android:exported="true">

    </provider>            
</application>
```

Content Provider User application AndroidManifest:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tshouse.contentprovidersuserbooks"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.tshouse.contentprovidersbooks.READ_DATABASE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.tshouse.contentprovidersbooks.WRITE_DATABASE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:readPermission="com.tshouse.contentprovidersbooks.READ_DATABASE"
    android:writePermission="com.tshouse.contentprovidersbooks.WRITE_DATABASE"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.tshouse.contentprovidersbooks.ContentProvidersUserBooks"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please advise how to declare the permission.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I had to guess, you installed the consumer app before the provider app, which will not work as you have it written.

If you put the `<permission>` elements in *both* apps, then the install order will not matter.

Also, you cannot put `android:readPermission` and `android:writePermission` on `<application>`, as you have in your consumer manifest. Simply delete those.

Comment: Thanks! 
Problem solved.
Found this [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/f8twQW8zdkA
proven working, same concept as you mentioned